# Constructing a Merkle tree of objects

Tags: keccak, merkle-patricia-tries

I can `keccak` strings to construct the leaves of a Merkle tree, for example, `['a', 'b', 'c']`. But what's the recommended approach to constructing objects instead of merely `'a'`? Let's say:

```
{
    address: "0x123",
    token: "0x456",
    amount: "15000000000000000000"
}
```

In Solidity, to verify that the object exists in the tree, a leaf would be constructed via `bytes32 leaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address, token, amount))` and that leaf would be verified along with the proof and root. How would you recommend constructing the above object as a leaf?

Can a leaf be constructed simply with `web3.utils.soliditySha3(param1 [, param2, ...])`? So if...

```
const hash0 = web3.utils.soliditySha3(address0, token0, amount0);
const hash1 = web3.utils.soliditySha3(address1, token1, amount1);
const leaves = [hash0, hash1]
const tree = new MerkleTree(leaves, keccak)
const proof = tree.getProof(hash0)
```

...would `leaves[0]` (`hash0`) in JS match `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address0, token0, amount0))` in Solidity?

Also, is this the right approach to adding objects to a Merkle tree, and what Merkle library would you recommend?

Comment: Yes, those two functions should return the same encoding assuming you specify the types of your params in the same way.

Comment: @SasaMilic turns out, I can't find a reliable Merkle library in JS/TS. Any you'd recommend? merkletreejs appears to be pre-production.

Comment: I've never had to directly use Merkle trees myself, so I can't help you there :(

Comment: have you tried `go-ethereum/trie` ? It does everything for you. You can also use `SecureTrie` version, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: look at the test files there, to see some examples

Comment: if you are working with Ethereum , then `Go` is the way to go, I wouldn't bother to write anything in JavaScript

Comment: @slider have you found any js/ts library for Merkle which will work with sol, I'm having a similar problem